# What do I need to play local co-op on Diablo 3?

Tags: ps4, diablo-iii-console

I want to play a game which I can play co-op with my daughter. After checking out some games, I have decided on Diablo 3. It interested me since I played Diablo years ago.

I have read things in several places about how to play co-op in Diablo 3 and I am really confused. Some people say that it is not possible since I'd need another Sony account, while others say I'd need two Diablo 3 accounts.

What I want to do is be able is to sit down with my girl, insert the disc, start the game, and have fun.

Is it possible if I only buy one copy of Diablo 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. In fact, I just had friends over recently and we all played my copy of Diablo 3 on my PS4.

You do not need multiple Blizzard accounts to play Diablo 3. You and your daughter will, however, each need a PSN account to log into the console and game with.

Once you are both logged in, the secondary player just has to hit the X button to join the game on the main menu (there will be a visual explaining this, as well). That's all you need to do to play local co-op for Diablo 3!

Comment: You just made my day :). Diablo 3 seems like a perfect games got coop :)

Comment: @VedranMaricevic no problem! I've actually been playing a ton of D3 lately

Comment: I bought it, and it worked like a charm :). We are hacking and slashing now.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic perfect. Glad to hear it :)